# Перевернуть двумерный массив c++

Tags: c++

Требуется перевернуть эту матрицу относительно вертикали, так чтобы первые элементы строк стали последними и наоборот.

Почему не работает этот код?

```
int matrix[10][10]={
{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10},
{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10},
{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10},
{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10},
{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10},
{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10},
{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10},
{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10},
{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10},
{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}
};
int* p=&matrix[10][10];
int buff[10][10];
int* p_buff=&buff[0][0];
while(*p_buff=*p--)*p_buff++;
```

На выводе случайные числа.

Comment: Почему вы не используете отладчик?

Comment: Как перевернуть? По вертикали, по горизонтали, относительно диагонали?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Переменная i не инициализирована, из - за этого в ней мусор, из-за этого и код не работает.

UPD:
Задачу вы решаете нерационально. Задачи о переворачивании удобно решать при помощи отражения от середины

```
for(size_t i=0; i < N/2; i++)
{
   swap(a[i],a[N-i-1]);
}
```

Мы тут переставляем первый с последним, предпоследний со вторым с конца и так далее.

Answer (score 3):

Похоже вы имеете в виду следующее:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    const size_t N = 10;

    int matrix[N][N] = 
    {
        { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 },
        { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 },
        { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 },
        { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 },
        { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 },
        { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 },
        { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 },
        { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 },
        { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 },
        { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 },
    };

    for ( const auto &row : matrix )
    {
        for ( int x : row ) std::cout << std::setw( 2 ) << x << ' ';
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }       
    std::cout << std::endl;

    int buff[N][N];

    for ( int *last = &matrix[N][0], *first = &matrix[0][0], *out = &buff[0][0];
          last != first; )
    {
        *out++ = *--last;
    }        

    for ( const auto &row : buff )
    {
        for ( int x : row ) std::cout << std::setw( 2 ) << x << ' ';
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }       
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::reverse_copy( &matrix[0][0], &matrix[N][0], &buff[0][0] );

    for ( const auto &row : buff )
    {
        for ( int x : row ) std::cout << std::setw( 2 ) << x << ' ';
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }       
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль:

```
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 

10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1 
10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1 
10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1 
10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1 
10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1 
10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1 
10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1 
10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1 
10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1 
10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1 

10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1 
10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1 
10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1 
10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1 
10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1 
10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1 
10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1 
10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1 
10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1 
10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1
```

В программе демонстрируются два подхода: аналогичный вашему с использованием цикла и с использованием стандартного алгоритма `std::reverse_copy`, объявленного в заголовке `<algorithm>`.

Что касается вашего кода, то выражение

```
&matrix[10][10]
```

не указывает на позицию, следующую за последним элементом массива `matrix`
Правильно будет использовать выражение

```
&matrix[N][0]
```

как показано в моей демонстрационной программе. То есть второй индекс должен быть равен 0.

Кроме того следующий цикл

```
while(*p_buff=*p--)*p_buff++;
```

просто не имеет смысла, так как цикл будет продолжаться до тех пор, пока не будут встречены нулевые байты, соответствующие значению `int( 0 )`, в памяти, не принадлежащей исходным массивам.